# Limit of alternating sequence

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $a < 0$ and let $a_n = \left ( \frac{an^2+bn+1}{n^2+3n-2} \right )^{n+1}, n \in \mathbb{N}$. I know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left ( \frac{an^2+bn+1}{n^2+3n-2} \right ) = a$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n+1 = \infty$. So $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ if $a \in (-1, 1)$,
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$ if $a > 1$. For $a=1$ i use a fundamental limit. But when $a < 0$ how I can calculate? On Wolfram Alpha it says something that limit is in a range of values. How can I show that this sequence doesn't have limit? Thanks!

$\textbf{Edit}$
So, if $b_n = \frac{an^2+bn+1}{n^2+3n-2} \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to} a < -1 \implies $ for a large value of $n$ we have that $b_n < -1$, and if $n+1$ is even we have that $b_n^{n+1} > 1$ and if $n+1$ is odd we have that $b_n^{n+1} < -1$. So the values alternates and this implies that limit of $a_n$ doesn't exists.

Is this proof ok? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah your proof is correct.

Comment: Is $n$ an integer? Please edit saying whether it is, even if your question is answered. Keep in mind that you post questions not just for yourself, but for others who may be interested and who may read this too.

Comment: @Mike yes $n$ is integer because $a_n$ is a sequence. I've edited anyway